# How do I parallelize/distribute queries/counts against a Spark DataFrame?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd, apache-spark-dataset

I have a `DataFrame` which I have to apply a series of filter queries against. For example, I load my `DataFrame` as follows.

```
val df = spark.read.parquet("hdfs://box/some-parquet")
```

I then have a bunch of "arbitrary" filters as follows.

- C0='true' and C1='false'
- C0='false' and C3='true'
- and so on...

I typically get these filters dynamically using a util method.

```
val filters: List[String] = getFilters()
```

All I do is apply these filters to the `DataFrame` to get the counts. For example.

```
val counts = filters.map(filter => {
 df.where(filter).count
})
```

I noticed that is NOT a parallel/distributed operation when mapping over the filters. If I stick the filters into an RDD/DataFrame, this approach won't work either, because I'd then be performing nested data frame operations (which, as I've read on SO, is not allowed in Spark). Something like the following gives a NullPointerException (NPE).

```
val df = spark.read.parquet("hdfs://box/some-parquet")
val filterRDD = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List("C0='false'", "C1='true'"))
val counts = filterRDD.map(df.filter(_).count).collect
```

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.filter(Dataset.scala:1127)
  at $anonfun$1.apply(:27)
  at $anonfun$1.apply(:27)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
  at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
  at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:104)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
  at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:310)
  at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1336)
  at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:302)
  at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1336)
  at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:289)
  at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1336)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$13.apply(RDD.scala:912)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$13.apply(RDD.scala:912)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1899)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1899)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Is there any way to parallelize/distribute the count filters on a `DataFrame` in Spark? By the way, I am on Spark v2.0.2.

Comment: Assuming what you want to achieve is a single pass over the input datas (otherwise, there may be no gain to expect out of this), I'd rework the filter functions to UDFs that return 1 (filter match) or 0 (no filter match), add 1 column by UDF to the dataframe, and do a groupBy / count on the added columns, which would result in a 1 row dataframe, holding all the counts.

Comment: could you show an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing that, the only expectable gain (which can be very substantial) would be to pass only once on the input data.

I would do it like so (programmatic solution, but equivalent SQL is possible) :

1. Convert your filters to UDFs that return 1 or 0
2. Add one column for each of these UDFS
3. Group By / sum your datas.

A sample spark session looks like :

```
scala> val data = spark.createDataFrame(Seq("A", "BB", "CCC").map(Tuple1.apply)).withColumnRenamed("_1", "input")

data: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [input: string]

scala> data.show
+-----+
|input|
+-----+
|    A|
|   BB|
|  CCC|
+-----+

scala> val containsBFilter = udf((input: String) => if(input.contains("B")) 1 else 0)
containsBFilter: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function1>,IntegerType,Some(List(StringType)))

scala> val lengthFilter = udf((input: String) => if (input.length < 3) 1 else 0)
lengthFilter: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function1>,IntegerType,Some(List(StringType)))

scala> data.withColumn("inputLength", lengthFilter($"input")).withColumn("containsB", containsBFilter($"input")).select(sum($"inputLength"), sum($"containsB")).show

+----------------+--------------+
|sum(inputLength)|sum(containsB)|
+----------------+--------------+
|               2|             1|
+----------------+--------------+
```

Comment: that's very clever. I like it. do you think using Scala's parallel collection class can help to parallelize as well? with your approach, as you stated, it's one pass over the data, but the UDFs would grow linearly with the amount of filters. but I guess that's ok if there's no performance hit.

Comment: I *guess* Spark is smart enough to handle just fine the additionnal columns (e.g. compute them by passing on the data only once), because they have no dependency. It does take more space, but we're talking longs, that's very efficient. Using parallel collections defeats the purpose of Spark : Spark partitions are the unit of parallelism (1 executor core = 1 partition), do not plug in you own (you'd only fight for CPUs with Spark partitions), just partition the right way.

Comment: I've been tinkering with this approach for a few days. I don't think it will work for my situation. First, about the parallel collection, this approach will only be parallelized on my driver program, not across the cluster, which is not what I intended. Second, I have to create these UDFs dynamically (I've asked another SO question). But even if I solved the problem of creating UDFs dynamically, the `df = df.withColumn("someFilter", someUdf(...))` operation is prohibitively long. I can have any number of dynamic UDFs (filters) and this will add that many columns.

Comment: I don't really get what is going on. Adding a column should be near instantaneous, it's only a logical plan update, no computation should be done. And I don't get either what is your parallel collection and how it fits into all this. Maybe it's for another question, though. As for transforming a filter into a UDF of 1/0, it could probably be done generically, though.